# C# LINQ Merge Dictionaries by comparing keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, linq-to-entities

I have 2 dictionaries as below

```
Dictionary<string, string> first= new Dictionary<string, string>();
 Dictionary<string, string> second = new Dictionary<string, string>();


first.Add("NAME", "NAME");
first.Add("TYPE", "TYPE");
first.Add("REF","REF");
first.Add("NUMBER", "NUMBER");
first.Add("DATE", "DATE");
first.Add("SOURCE", "SOURCE");

second.Add("TYPE", "T1");
second.Add("REF","A1234");
second.Add("NUMBER", "B456");
second.Add("DATE", "D123455");
second.Add("NAME", "NAME");
second.Add("SOURCE", "SOURCE");
```

How to achieve a resulting dictionary  like below

```
("NAME", "NAME");
("TYPE", "T1");
("REF","A1234");
("NUMBER", "B456");
("DATE", "D123455");
("SOURCE", "SOURCE");
```

Ideally first and second merged together  with the values from second merged onto first and the keys should retain in the order of first dictionary.
Could anyone suggest the best approach to achieve this, Thanks.

Comment: The best approach would be to write some code.

Comment: Also dictionaries have no inherent order. You will need a list or array for that.

Comment: You can also use `SortedSet<T>`, but you have to implement the `IComparer` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var result = first.Union(second)
                   .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
                   .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Value = x.Last().Value })
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

First you are union both of collections, after that group them by the keys selects the `Last().Value` for the value and converting it again to `Dictionary`.

Here [**Full example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/owUA0z)

Comment: Non starter: "and the keys should retain in the order of first dictionary" will not work with a dictionary

Comment: @GoneCoding you can check the full example that they are in same order.

Comment: You cannot count on that. The order is not guaranteed for dictionaries. That it works in some situations is misleading the OP into a bad habit. That is why they also have SortedDictionary class http://www.go4expert.com/articles/understanding-c-sharp-dictionaries-t30034/